# What is the solution of this limit

Tags: limits

The limit is:

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4}\frac{32^{\frac12} - (\cos x + \sin x)^5}{1-\sin(2x)}$$

Use radians

My question is:

1. How to do it without calculator.
2. Show me the steps on how it's being done.

I prefer answer that didn't use derivatives or L'Hospital's Rule, but if there's no way then it's okay to use them

Edit 2: when I use calculator, the answer is $5\sqrt{2}$

Edit 3:

I have tried: substituting $\sqrt{2}$ with $\cos(\pi/4)+\cos(\pi/4)$ and substituting 1 with $\sin(\pi/4)^2+\cos(\pi/4)^2$ and substituting $\sin 2x$ with $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Resulting: $\frac{(\cos(\pi/4)+\sin(\pi/4))-(\cos(x)+\sin(x))}{\sin(\pi/2)-\sin2x}$

$\frac{(\cos(\pi/4)-\cos(x))+(\sin(\pi/4)-\sin(x))}{2\cos(\pi/4+x)\sin(\pi/4-x)}$

$\frac{-\sin(\pi/8+x/2)\sin(\pi/8-x/2)+\cos(\pi/8+x/2)\sin(\pi/8-x/2)}{\cos(\pi/4+x)\sin(\pi/4-x)}$

$\frac{\sin(\pi/8-x/2)[-\sin(\pi/8+x/2)+\cos(\pi/8+x/2)]}{\cos(\pi/4+x)\sin2(\pi/8-x/2)}$

$\frac{\sin(\pi/8-x/2)[-\sin(\pi/8+x/2)+\cos(\pi/8+x/2)]}{\cos(\pi/4+x)2\sin(\pi/8-x/2)\cos(\pi/8-x/2)}$

eliminate $\sin(\pi/8-x/2)$

$\frac{-\sin(\pi/8+x/2)+\cos(\pi/8+x/2)}{2\cos(\pi/4+x)\cos(\pi/8-x/2)}$ progress

then I'm stuck here. I can't eliminate anything

Comment: "How to do it without calculator"?? I'd rather ask how to do it **with** calculator!

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to open math se for some time because I'm somewhere where internet connection is quite hard to get. I will accept your answer in a day or two

Comment: @Timbuc: trying values of $x$ closer and closer to $\pi/4$ the function converges to $7.071067...$ before it diverges because of truncation. These decimals have a taste of "déja vu". Squaring, you get $49.9999885$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we will use $\cos x + \sin x = \sqrt 2 \cos(\pi/4 - x).$  now, we will make a change of variable $x = \pi/4 +h.$

so the numerator can be simplifies as:

$\begin{align}4\sqrt2 - (\sin x + \cos x)^5 &= 4\sqrt2(1-\cos^5h) \\
&=4\sqrt2(1-\cos   h)(1+\cos h + \cos^2h + \cos^3h + \cos^4h)\\
&= 4\sqrt2(\frac12 h^2+\cdots)(5+\cdots)\\
&=10\sqrt2 h^2 + \cdots\end{align}$

looking at the denominator $$ 1- \sin 2x = 1 - \sin(\pi/2 + 2h) = 1 -\cos 2h = 1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}(2h)^2 + \cdots \right)=2h^2 + \cdots$$

therefore the $$\lim_{x \to \pi/4} \frac{32^{1/2}-(\cos x + \sin x)^5}{1 - \sin 2x} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{10\sqrt2 h^2 + \cdots}{2h^2 + \cdot} = 5\sqrt 2. $$

Comment: You are wrong by a factor $2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thanks. fixed now.

Comment: @abel =42√(1−cosh)(1+cosh+cos2h+cos3h+cos4h)=42√(12h2+⋯)(5+⋯) How is that even posibble? (line 4-5)

Comment: @Kristian,  i don't understand your comment.  $(1-\cos^5h) = (1-\cos h)(5+\cdots) = 5/2 h^2 + \cdots$

Comment: @abel how is line 4-5 possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can write

$$\sqrt{32} - (\cos x + \sin x)^5 = \sqrt{2}^5 - (\cos x + \sin x)^5 =\\= (\sqrt{2} - (\cos x + \sin x))\cdot S(x)$$ where $$S(x)= (\sqrt{2}^4 + \sqrt{2}^3(\cos x + \sin x) + \sqrt{2}^2(\cos x +\sin x)^2 +\\+\sqrt 2(\cos x +\sin x)^4 + (\cos x +\sin x)^4)$$

Now you know that $S(\pi/4) = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 20\neq 0$, so

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4} \frac{(\sqrt{32} - (\cos x + \sin x)^5)}{1-\sin(2x)} = S(\pi/4)\cdot \lim_{x\to\frac\pi4} \frac{\sqrt{2} - (\cos x + \sin x)}{1-\sin (2x)}$$

At this point, you should use formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$ to simplify the two expressions on the top and bottom. You can, for example, write $\sqrt{2} = \cos\frac\pi4 + \sin\frac\pi4$ and play around from there. Try a couple of formulas out and let us know how far you got. If you are still stuck, I can provide further hints, but it's better if you to work it out, or at the very least, give it a few tries.

Comment: After getting out 20 from the limit, I have problem eliminating the rest as it would end as 0/0. I have tried four or five times but I still got 0/0. From calculator I got the answer as 5*root(2). Could you give me further hints?

Comment: @Kristian Did you try using formulas which help you manipulate trigonometric functions? There are formulas that can transform addition into multiplication, for example.

Comment: Okay, now I give up. Please tell me the answer already... none of my tries worked so far, they all produce 0/0.

Comment: @Kristian If you edit your question with what you already tried, I can help you further. I will not simply tell you the answer because that will help nobody.

Comment: I have show what I have tried. Sorry for not using mathjax because I'm editing it from my cellphone

Comment: @Kristian You substituted $\sin(2x)$ with $2\sin^2 x$, which is not equal...

Comment: I have edited it again. Now I'm really stuck here. Please help

Comment: @Kristian How did you get rid of all values of $x$ in the numerator? You should have some $x$ in the top of the fraction...

Comment: Okay. Fixed. But still stuck

Comment: @Kristian I am repeating my hint because you have obviously not used it. As I said yesterday, **There are formulas that can transform addition into multiplication**. Did you try using them? Did you look them up? Did you do anything with my hint?

Comment: Hint used. Please tell me what to do next. It would create 0/0 with direct substitution.

Comment: You made progress! The numerator is now equal to $\sin\left(\frac\pi8 - \frac x2\right)$ multiplied by something not equal $0$ when $x=\frac\pi4$. Now you must do the same with the denominator, in which I suggest you replace $1$ with $\sin\left(2\cdot \frac\pi4\right)$ instead of what you did.

Comment: What's next? I have eliminated $\sin(\pi/8-x/2)$ Please help

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{32^{\frac12} - (\cos x + \sin x)^5}{1-\sin(2x)}=4\sqrt2\frac{1-\cos^5(x-\pi/4))}{1-\cos(2(x-\pi/4))}=2\sqrt2\frac{1-\cos^5(x-\pi/4)}{1-\cos^2(x-\pi/4)}.$$
By an obvious change of variable,

$$\lim_{t\to1}\frac{1-t^5}{1-t^2}=\lim_{t\to1}\frac{1+t+t^2+t^3+t^4}{1+t}.$$

You can conclude.